# What can a person use instead of enum for an intellisense aware collection of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Currently using an enum for a list of filenames in an application for the ability to use intellisense and to make sure the filename is one of the existing files (the enum prevents typos and having to remember each filename verbatim). There are currently 107 files in the enum. In order to get an audio file name the enum value ToString() method is used.

Now there is a situation where there needs to be some filenames added based on the result of a database call. This isn't possible with an enum and will require a lot of application restructuring to implement (changing all methods that take an enum to take a string).

What should have been done in the first place or is an enum the best option for this use case?

Comment: How do you get the file path from the enum value?

Comment: You could have just used `const string MyFile1 = "myfile.txt";` in a normal class. (`const` is if you don't wan't the value to be changed that is.)

Comment: @devdigital Only storing the file names, the path is provided elsewhere. The names are retrieved by taking the EnumValue.ToString().

Comment: I you get the files from the database you are going to have to use some kind of collection. Perhaps a `HashSet<string>`

Comment: What are you using for a datalayer? EntityFramework 5 has explicit support for enums so that you can generate an enum automatically from a list of rows in your files table. If you aren't using EF then your next best bet is to map the FileNames (not paths, the friendly name of the file that can be mapped to an enum) to the FileID from your table.

Comment: Thanks Heather, the application is using ADO.NET.

Comment: @narohi +1 I guess you can comment everywhere now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of the use case, but one consideration is resource files. You would get intellisense, and the added bonus of being able to change the file names per localisation.

See [here](http://www.dev102.com/2008/10/20/how-to-localize-your-application-using-string-tables/) for an example.

Comment: How do you get intellisense with resource files?

Comment: @Blam - Of course, you have to add the Resource to your Resources area in settings first...

Comment: I feel like this needs an answer in itself, but just for more clarification, Right-Click Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource

Comment: @DanVanWinkle OK I added two string resources R1 and R2 but I cannot figure out how to access them.

Comment: For the items that are obtained from the database, resources are going to be filled at runtime. You wouldn't be able to get intellisense for that.

Comment: @Blam - Should just have to type in <DefaultNamespace>.Properties.Resources.R1 and <DefaultNamespace>.Properties.Resources.R2...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would, indeed, be to simply list every file as a string constant.  But that makes it frustrating to add new content, and if you ever wanted to add new sounds, you'd have to recompile and distribute *the entire application*.

Instead of that, consider listing your sound files in a single data file (XML, perhaps?).  Inside your program, import the data as a string-key, string-value dictionary, where your keys are the name of the sound and the values are the filenames.  Build a wrapper class to hold the dictionary so you can handle errors gracefully, and voila! You have access to your sounds, AND you can add and remove sounds from outside the code itself.

Plus, when you make your database call, all you need to do is add the additional sound data to your dictionary.

Comment: Intellisense really isn't worth it in the long run, by the way.  Resources should always be kept separate from code.

Comment: If a database call is already required why a separate XML.  I would just put them all in the database.   How is every file in a string constant better than an enum?

Comment: Actually, in this case it's probably worse.  I was addressing some of the comments in the original question.  The database call was in reference to the question's constraints, where they had some set of preset resources, but could later add more from database calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create a static class with constant members.

```
static class FileNames
{
    public const string FirstFileName = "FirstFileName.txt";
    //and so on
}
```

In case for the database part (that isn't elaborated and leaves room for guesses) you can use a **T4 template** that generates a class in which there is a list of file names declared in the form above. The T4 template can make the database call during design time using regular ADO .NET code, then the result of the query can be used to output the file names and constant members.

It is very worth while to discover T4: check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx.